# How to create Microsoft Access database in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

How do you create a Microsoft Access database file in C# if it does not exist yet?

Comment: Does it have to be access or are you looking for a file based database solution to store data? SQLite is nice and portable if that's all you need.

Comment: Yeah I am now using SQLite on Android.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest answer is to embed an empty `.mdb` / `.accdb` file in your program and write it out to disk.

The correct answer is to use COM Interop with the ADOX library:

```
var cat = new ADOX.Catalog()
cat.Create(connectionString);
```

Remember to generate your connection strings using `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: Hint: The "ADOX library" could be found as "Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security" on my machine

Comment: I have an error **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Class not registered**

Comment: anyone know why the Class not registered happening?

Comment: @g00n3r Do you have an installed version of Office or Access?

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
using ADOX; //Requires Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security
using ADODB;

public bool CreateNewAccessDatabase(string fileName)
{
bool result = false; 

ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();

//Create the table and it's fields. 
table.Name = "Table1";
table.Columns.Append("Field1");
table.Columns.Append("Field2");

try
{
    cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
    cat.Tables.Append(table);

    //Now Close the database
    ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
    if (con != null)
    con.Close();

    result = true; 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result = false;
}
cat = null;
return result;
}
```

http://zamirsblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/creating-access-database.html

Comment: good example!
remember `using ADODB; // Requires ADODB in .Net framework`

Answer (score 13):

On my computer, Windows 7 sp1 Professional 64-bit, I found Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security in *C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msadox28.dll*.

It is also found as a reference:

[image]

which is included as **ADOX** in the references

[image]

By default, columns are created as **text[255]**.  Here are a few examples to create columns as different datatypes.

```
table.Columns.Append("PartNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 6); // text[6]
table.Columns.Append("AnInteger", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger); // Integer
```

I found this list of datatypes to create and read access database fields

> Access Text = adVarWChar
>
> Access Memo = adLongVarWChar
>
> Access Numeric Byte = adUnsignedTinyInt
>
> Access Numeric Integer = adSmallInt
>
> Access Numeric Long Integer = adInteger
>
> Access Numeric Single Precision = adSingle
>
> Access Numeric Double Precision = adDouble
>
> Access Numeric Replicatie-id = adGuid
>
> Access Numeric Decimal = adNumeric
>
> Access Date / Time = adDate
>
> Access Currency = adCurrency
>
> Access AutoNumber = adInteger
>
> Access Yes / No = adBoolean
>
> Access HyperLink = adLongVarWChar

Comment: Comment noted.  Just following up on Zamir's comment.

Comment: Just a very late note on the fact that if you want to make an AutoNumber column you have to set the `AutoIncrement` value to true. This happens after creating the Catalog, where you set the `ParentCatalog` for the column as your Catalog, then set the column's `Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CreateDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-createdatabase-method-dao) method in the DAO / ACE library (it's installed with Office, or available for download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)).

```
// using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
// using static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DatabaseTypeEnum;

const string dbLangGeneral = ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0";

var engine = new DBEngine();
var dbs = engine.CreateDatabase(@"c:\path\to\database.accdb", dbLangGeneral, dbVersion120);
dbs.Close();
dbs = null;
```

Note that depending on the version of Access/Jet you want your database to support, you can use other values from the `DatabaseTypeEnum` enum:

- `dbVersion10`
- `dbVersion11`
- `dbVersion20`
- `dbVersion30`
- `dbVersion40`
- `dbVersion120`
- `dbVersion140`
- `dbVersion150`

Also note that you can choose to encrypt the database, or select a different collation.

NB: If you have a 64-bit machine, and want to run the code as part of a 64-bit program, you'll need the 64-bit version of the engine. If you already have the 32-bit version installed (either via Office, or via the download), you'll have to run the 64-bit installer with the `/passive` and `/silent` flags; otherwise you'll get a message that you can't install 64-bit components over previously installed 32-bit components.